# Unable to Start adb server with start-server command on windows

Tags: android, adb

I am beginner in android development and i am unable to start ADB server i am getting the below mention error

```
E:\ANDRIOD\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server 

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 
* error: Invalid argument: cannot open transport registration socketpair could not read ok from ADB Server 
* failed to start daemon 
* error: cannot connect to daemon
```

i have tried restarting the windows and my sdk platforms tools are also updated to version 24 and sdk tools to ver 25.1.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and solved it stopping my firewall. 
Later I had to configure it to allow some ports to be used by adb.

If that works for you too, consider this:

When you start an adb client, the client first checks whether there is an adb server process already running. If there isn't, it starts the server process. When the server starts, it binds to local TCP port 5037 and listens for commands sent from adb clients—all adb clients use port 5037 to communicate with the adb server.

The server then sets up connections to all running emulator/device instances. It locates emulator/device instances by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585, the range used by emulators/devices. Where the server finds an adb daemon, it sets up a connection to that port. Note that each emulator/device instance acquires a pair of sequential ports — an even-numbered port for console connections and an odd-numbered port for adb connections. For example:

Emulator 1, console: 5554
Emulator 1, adb: 5555
Emulator 2, console: 5556
Emulator 2, adb: 5557
and so on...

(from https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#issuingcommands
See here for details)